# Как избавиться от несколько копий модуля Node.js

Tags: node.js

В моем приложении на Node.js искользуется несколько модулей с зависимостями и в результате один и тот же модуль несколько раз устанавливается. Можно как-нибудь с этим бороться?

Comment: Использовать npm3. Или https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe